# 50 MB Image uses 1 GB of RAM as Texture

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl, ram

I'm using LWJGL to create an OpenGL 3D application. For importing my images (for UV mapping) and converting them to Textures I use Slick2D:

```
bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(renderEngine.class.getResource("/images/textures/Stargate/image8192.png"));
objTextures.get(1)[0] = BufferedImageUtil.getTexture("", bufferedImage).getTextureID();
```

This method (second line) instantly uses 1 GB of RAM, but my Image has only the size of 8192x8192 --> 50 MB.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Why are they stored in RAM and not on the graphics card?

Comment: @Geosearchef: OpenGL uses an abstract memory model; to implement this it is necessary to keep a copy of the texture data around, since other applications, or the OS may require the graphics card's RAM for their purposes. Also GPUs can crash and to make the driver restart transparent to the applications a copy of the resources are required. In short: The RAM on a graphics card is mostly a cache, and for almost everything in GPU RAM there's a shadow copy in system RAM.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Yea, that was a mistake. It should be `8192*8192*4 = 256MB`, though that's still a bit bigger than 50MB.

Answer (score 3):

The amount of raw space depends on a number of things.

What is the [color model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getColorModel--)?

What is the [data type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/SampleModel.html#getDataType--) of the [sample model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSampleModel--)?

Using an image type of [TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR) would lead to a minimum size of 256MB (8K * 8K * 4).

Using a data type of int (instead of byte) could increase that 4x.

And this is just the first line of reading into a `BufferedImage`.